# Easy way to get source files from doxygen documentation?

Tags: doxygen

I have found the source for a game that I am interested in modifying, and it's in the form of doxygen "documentation".

Under "files" I get html files with names not related to the cpp and h files, and also line numbers.

I was wondering if there is a way to convert the doxygen documentation into regular cpp and h files.

Answer (score 0):

How many files are there? If not too many, a manual copy-paste perhaps...

[html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) is a python program that is pretty good at converting html to, well, text.